# How to use multiple classes in list project java

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I cannot wrap my mind around a useful way to use classes. To illustrate my problem: I want to write a program that will allow me to create shopping lists and divide the entries according to categories. So i would:

(Step 1) - create a list with products and the productcategories which they belong into, possibly with an array list

(Step 2) let the user choose which supermarket he goes to and then print out the list divided in categoeries which are arranged in different orders based on which supermarket the user chose

(and a couple other options as well)

Now all i've written so far in Java was limited to one class and one class only. But it has been suggested to me that writing in multiple classes would be beneficial. As i said before i cannot wrap my head around in which fashion it would make sense in this example. Maybe someone with a better understanding can give me a quick hint?

Here is how i would tackle this in one class (I took the actual code out for readability and since the actual implementation doesn't really matter to this question i figured):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    ArrayList<String> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    private static void spellInstructions(){
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Choose one of the following options. Press ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(1)" + "\t--\t" + "to add an item to list");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(2)" + "\t--\t" + "to display your list");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(3)" + "\t--\t" + "to choose a supermarket");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(4)" + "\t--\t" + "to replace item on your list");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(5)" + "\t--\t" + "to delete item from your list");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(6)" + "\t--\t" + "to search for an item on your list");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(7)" + "\t--\t" + "to qoit this application");

        getUserInput();
    }
    private static void getUserInput(){}
    private static void addItemToList(){}
    private static void displayList(){}
    private static void chooseSupermarket(){}
    private static void replaceItem(){}
    private static void deleteItem(){}
    private static void searchItem(){}
    private static void quitApp(){}
}
```

Comment: A good start is to look at what nouns you are using in your description since a noun is a good candidate for a class, like _product_, _shopping list_, _user_, _product category_ and _supermarket_ for instance.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/object-oriented-programming-concepts-21bb035f7260/). Maybe this will help.